# Referenced object by pointers and arrays

Tags: arrays, pointers

I am trying to solve a very trivial exercise from Hackerrank Warmup challenges.

Here is the code :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2, int *result_size)
{
    // Complete this function
    int r[2];
    r[0] = 0;
    r[1] = 0;

    if( a0 > b0)
        r[0] += 1;
    else if( a0 < b0)
        r[1] += 1;

     if( a1 > b1)
        r[0] += 1;
    else if( a1 < b1)
        r[1] += 1;

    if( a2 > b2)
        r[0] += 1;
    else if( a2 < b2)
        r[1] += 1;
    //p = r;
    *result_size = 2;
    printf("The one %i and the two %i : \n", r[0],r[1]);
    return r;
}

int main() 
{

    int a0;
    int a1;
    int a2;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &a0, &a1, &a2);

    int b0;
    int b1;
    int b2;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &b0, &b1, &b2);

    int result_size;
    int* result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, &result_size);
    printf("The ptr one %i and the ptr two %i : \n", result[0],*(result + 1));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("%i ", result[i]);
    printf(" result_size %i \n ", result_size);

    int result_i;
    for(result_i = 0; result_i < result_size; result_i++)
    {
        if(result_i)
       {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("%i", result[result_i]);
    }
   // puts("");


    return 0;
}
```

I get a good result inside the function and inside the main function. But when I try to iterate through the array returned from the "solve function" in the for-loop, it seems like I am getting the address of the referenced object, but not its actual content. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your good result and what is expected output?

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand the problem by looking at the compiler warnings:

> warning: function returns address of local variable

This means that in your `solve` function you are returning the address of a variable created inside it, here:

```
int* solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2, int *result_size)
{
    int r[2];
    ...
    return r;
}
```

To understand why this is wrong you need understand that the variables created inside a function are stored in stack memory. When a function is called a block of stack memory is used and all its variables are stored in it, so when the same function returns the previously used stack block is released.

Therefore **you shouldn't access variables that were created in a function from outside**, and if you do you will get an undefined behavior.

To fix this you can allocate memory on the heap with `malloc`, like so:

```
int* solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2, int *result_size)
{
    int *r = malloc(sizeof(r) * 2);
    ...
```

Now the memory is allocated on the heap and won't be cleared when the function ends.

Don't forget that you should call `free` to release the respective memory block when you no longer need it.